# PouchDB Replication Fails with Empty Error

Tags: javascript, electron, pouchdb

I'm attempting to replicate a remote CouchDB database to a local one. I can successfully access the remote docs and create a local PouchDB instance. However, as soon as I initiate a replication or sync command, I'm returned a PouchDB error with an empty array (i.e. no message, code, etc.).

```
// This is the portion of code that is failing:
try {
    var result = await localDb.replicate.from(remoteDb)
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

The `local.ini` file on the CouchDB server has the following options set:

```
[chttpd]
port = 5984
bind_address = 192.168.1.1

[httpd]
enable_cors = true

[cors]
origins = *
```

Any ideas?